# How to redirect domain to test server IP using bridged wlan0 to eth0 connection?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet, access-point

Following this tutorial https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md from 
"Using the Raspberry Pi as an access point to share an internet connection (bridge)" section.

My aim is to allow connections that are connected to the access point of the RPi to go to our work website, then be redirected to the ip address of the test server of the work website.

I have thought of adding the ip address in the /etc/hosts file but this doesn't redirect the devices that are connected to the access point, it only redirects me when I use the physical raspberry pi browser.

Am I doing this wrong?

phone --> RPi --(internet)--> website domain --> test server

Comment: I do not understand. You have a RasPi and a (internet) router. The RasPi is connected to the router with a bridge. On the router is also connected a device presenting your private local work website. So this device should redirect to the test server instead of presenting the work website? It should work as proxy to the test server?

Comment: You should configure the raspberry's dns to point the domain you want to the test server's ip. Check this ubuntu question https://askubuntu.com/questions/53523/how-to-redirect-a-url-to-a-custom-ip-address